# Prove the $S=\left\{f \in C^1([0,1]):\||f |\| \leq 1\right\}$ is not closed in $C([0,1])$ with respect to the usual supremum norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$C^1([0,1])=\left\{f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f\right.$ is differentiable and $f^{\prime}$ is continuous $\}$.

Given $\||f |\|=\|f\|_{\infty}+\left\|f^{\prime}\right\|_{\infty} $.
Prove the $S=\left\{f \in C^1([0,1]):\||f |\| \leq 1\right\}$ is not closed in $C([0,1])$ with respect to the usual supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ on $C([0,1])$.

To prove that the given S is not closed in $C([0,1])$, I have to find an example Cauchy sequence in the space which doesn't converge in the space. However I have no idea for that.

Any hint for finding the sequence is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn’t this contradict Arzela-Ascoli if it were closed? Are you sure you have the norms right?

Comment: @Nick Sorry I worked on the wrong space, the $C^1[0,1]$ is a Banach space. The right space should be $C[0,1]$ with usual supremum norm.

Comment: Would $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{4}|x - \frac{1}{2}|^{1 + 1/n}$ work? Each term is in $S$, and the sequence converges uniformly (i.e., with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm in $C([0, 1])$) to $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}|x - \frac{1}{2}|$, which is not in $S$.

Comment: @nowhere Yes, that is a good example.

Comment: @nowhere If I understand correctly, the $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ so $f(x)$ is not in S. That is a good example, thanks!

Comment: @Rita Yes. Each term is differentiable everywhere, but the limit is not differentiable at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. Do you need a proof for why the sequence converges uniformly?

Comment: @nowhere If would be helpful if you wish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand on my previous comment.

To show that $S$ is not closed in $C([0, 1])$ with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, it suffices to exhibit a sequence of functions $f_n \in S$ that converges to a limit $f$ with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm (i.e, uniform convergence), but the limit $f$ fails to be in $S$.

Consider $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{4}|x - \frac{1}{2}|^{1 + 1/n}$. Each term is continuously differentiable, and satisfies $\||f_n|\|_\infty \leq 1$. (The constant $\frac{1}{4}$ was chosen to make sure that $\||f_n|\|_\infty \leq 1$.) You can check by a direct computation.

The sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}|x - \frac{1}{2}|$. To see this, consider the function $g(x, t) = |x - \frac{1}{2}|^t$. By the mean value bound, we have
\begin{align*}
\Big||x - \frac{1}{2}|^{1 + 1/n} - |x - \frac{1}{2}|^1\Big| & = |g(x, 1 + 1/n) - g(x, 1)|\\
& \leq \frac{1}{n}\max_{1 \leq t \leq 1 + 1/n} \Big|\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x, t)\Big|.
\end{align*}
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x, t) = |x - \frac{1}{2}|^t \ln |x - \frac{1}{2}|$, and for $x \in [0, 1]$, $t \in [1, 2]$,
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x, t)\Big| & = \big|x - \frac{1}{2}\big|^{t - 1}\Big|\big|x - \frac{1}{2}\big|\ln\big|x - \frac{1}{2}\big|\Big|\\
& \leq \Big|\big|x - \frac{1}{2}\big|\ln\big|x - \frac{1}{2}\big|\Big|\\
& \leq C,
\end{align*}
where $C$ is some constant independent of $x$ and $t$. We have now established
$$\Big||x - \frac{1}{2}|^{1 + 1/n} - |x - \frac{1}{2}|^1\Big| \leq C/n$$ which implies uniform convergence.

The limit $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}|x - \frac{1}{2}|$ is, of course, not differentiable at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. So $f \notin S$.